# Excel VBA Autofilter field as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to develop a code that will autofilter a field, that will change month to month.

I have a userform where the user selects the reporting month, then the script finds that month across the top of a structured table, and then drops down 1 row to select the header of the structured table. upon clicking "OK" on the user form.

As the field number "column" will change each time I need to enter this as a variable. I have tried a number of different solutions from other peoples posts, but still no luck.

I don't remember all the different combinations I've tried now.

```
Private Sub cbOK_Click()
Sheets("Weekly Timesheet").Select
Sheets("Weekly Timesheet").Range("H5").Select
ActiveCell.value = cboRMonth.value
Unload Me

ReportMonth = cboRMonth.value
MsgBox ReportMonth

Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Select
Sheets("Tracking (DAYS)").Range("N2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell = ReportMonth
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Tells me what the name of the header is (just to make sure I've got the 
right one selected).
Dim Col As String
Col = ActiveCell
MsgBox Col

Dim lCol As Long
lCol = ActiveCell.Column

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tracking_DAYS").Range(lCol).AutoFilter _
Criterial:=">0", _
Operator:=x1FilterValues

End Sub
```

I'm expecting to be able to filter a column of the table based on the output of the userform to values greater than 0.

Comment: You want to filter a Range of Values ? from 0 to Something ?

Comment: I'm wanting to filter a range of values greater than 0.  That's not the bit I'm having trouble with though.

I need the AutoFilter Field to be a variable value as the column that needs filtering will change monthly.

Comment: what is this in your Code ? `ListObjects("Tracking_DAYS")`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:="VARIABLE NAME", Criterial:=">0", Operator:=xlFilterValues` .. This line should do your Job. Here you can change the Variable name and enter your variable without quotes.

Comment: The `ListObjects("Tracking_DAYS")` line is referring to the table name where the columns are.
Do I need t change the `.UsedRange.` to anything defining?

Could you please help me visualise what I need to call it out as - sorry, relatively new to vba.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make the field that is filtered in a table dynamic so I first set up a variable that finds the field name (in this case "Year") that I want and gives me the column number of that field:

```
Range("A1").Select

Dim YC As Long

YC = Rows(1).Find("Year").Column
```

Then I can use that variable as the field number:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").Range.AutoFilter Field:=YC, Criteria1:=Year(Date)
```